# Volume of 3D objects

Tags: calculus, solid-of-revolution

The graph is to be revolved around the line $y=4$

Consider the functions
$$f(x)=\frac{2}{x+1}$$
$$y=0$$
$$x=0$$
$$x=4$$
So this means we need to use the washer method but where i'm stuck on is what  $r$ is meant to be. I know $R$ is $R(x)=4- \frac{2}{x+1}$ but should I use $x=0$ and $x=4$ or just one of them for $r$?

Comment: Washers are a good idea.  Draw the solid, then find the outer and inner radius of each cross section in terms of $x$.  The “outer radius” is the distance from the center of the revolution to the outermost point.  The “inner radius” is the distance from the center to the innermost point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Washer method is fine.

The larger radius is $4$ and the smaller radius is

$$4-\frac {2}{x+1}$$

The bounds of your integral are $x=0$ and $x=4$

The integrand is  $$\pi (4^2-( 4-\frac {2}{x+1})^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

By [**disk method**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disc_integration), the set up should be

$$V=\int_0^4 \pi 4^2dx-\int_0^4 \pi[4-f(x)]^2 dx$$

Answer (score 0):

You have to use every element 0 to 4 since you are integrating, so Your volume is 
$$V=\int_{0}^{4}\pi[4-{2 \over x+1}]^2dx$$